# Uploading an image in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Hi Iam trying to upload an image in cakephp  but it is inserting only jpg in database table iam getting error as

Warning (2): move_uploaded_file(C:\xampp\htdocs\practise\app\webroot\img\image\3.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [APP\Controller\UsersController.php, line 98]

Warning (2): move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php24B4.tmp' to 'C:\xampp\htdocs\practise\app\webroot\img\image\3.jpg' [APP\Controller\UsersController.php, line 98]

Here is my code

Controller:

```
$extension =strtolower(pathinfo($this->request->data['User']['image_file']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            if( 
                !empty ($this->request->data['User']['image_file']['tmp_name'])&&
                in_array($extension,array('png','jpeg','jpg'))
              )
              {
                move_uploaded_file
                (
                    $this->request->data['User']['image_file']['tmp_name'],
                    IMAGES.'image'.DS.$this->User->id.'.'. $extension
                );
                $this->User->saveField('image',$extension);
              }
              elseif(!empty ($this->request->data['User']['image_file']['tmp_name']))
```

And View:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User',array('type' =>'file'));?>
<?php echo $this->Form- >input('image_file',array('label'=>'Image(jpeg,jpg,png)','type' =>'file'));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end();?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your image folder path is correct?

C:\xampp\htdocs\practise\app\webroot\img\image\3.jpg

**image** folder exists in your **img** folder?

Please replace this

```
move_uploaded_file($this->request->data['User']['image_file']['tmp_name'],IMAGES.'image'.DS.$this->User->id.'.'. $extension);

$this->User->saveField('image',$extension);
```

**to**

```
move_uploaded_file($this->request->data['User']['image_file']['tmp_name'],IMAGES.'image'.DS.$this->request->data['User']['image_file']['name']);

$this->User->saveField('image',$this->request->data['User']['image_file']['name']);
```

Comment: `move_uploaded_file
                (
                    $this->request->data['User']['image_file']['tmp_name'],
                    IMAGES.'image'.DS.$this->User->id.'.'. $extension
                );` have u created the **image**  folder?

Comment: Ha i created the folder in webroot/img/uploads

Comment: Hope you got the solution :)

Comment: But in database it is saving as only jpg it is not saving the image name

Comment: `$this->User->saveField('image',$extension);` Your saving the extension alone?  Please change that to name

Comment: But in folder it is saving as 1.jpg,2.jpg actually it should save as filename.jpg and in database it is only saving as jpg

Comment: Iam not getting what you are saying where i have change the name can you please say that

Comment: Getting the same errors                                                                       Warning (2): move_uploaded_file(C:\xampp\htdocs\practise\app\webroot\img\uploads\C:\xampp\tmp\php8CE1.tmp.jpg): failed to open stream: Invalid argument [APP\Controller\UsersController.php, line 98]

Warning (2): move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php8CE1.tmp' to 'C:\xampp\htdocs\practise\app\webroot\img\uploads\C:\xampp\tmp\php8CE1.tmp.jpg' [APP\Controller\UsersController.php, line 98]

Comment: I have changed the code getting the same error only.My database column name is image

Comment: Please check the answer now

Comment: No Getting the error as  Warning (2): move_uploaded_file(C:\xampp\htdocs\practise\app\webroot\img\image\bird-75.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [APP\Controller\UsersController.php, line 94]

Warning (2): move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpDE32.tmp' to 'C:\xampp\htdocs\practise\app\webroot\img\image\bird-75.jpg' [APP\Controller\UsersController.php, line 94]

Comment: please change your upload folder accordingly

Comment: Could please accept the answer so your question wont remain unanswered :) Thanks

Comment: Can u please tell me how to accept the answer iam not able to find